# Making the first cell of a UICollectionView focused on tvOS

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

OK, if I have a `UIViewController` I can make a view focused on tvOS if I use this `preferredFocusedView but what about making the first cell of a UICollectionView focused? How do I do that?

I have tried to create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and have the method

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
   return ([self ifThisIsTheFirstCell]) ? self : nil;
}
```

without success.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way "preferred focus" works conceptually is that there's a "chain" of objects starting at your app's window, going down through view controllers and views, until the chain ends at a focusable view. That view at the end is what will get focused when your app launches, or if focus needs to be reset (for example, if the currently-focused view gets removed from the view hierarchy, UIKit will need to choose another view to become focused). The `preferredFocusedView` method is how you define the chain.

For example, `UIWindow` implements `preferredFocusedView` to return the preferred focused view of the `rootViewController`. In the abstract, t's doing something like this:

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    return [self.rootViewController preferredFocusedView];
}
```

`UIViewController` implements `preferredFocusedView` to return it's `view` property. `UIView` just returns itself.

However, `UICollectionView` implements `preferredFocusedView` differently: in the simplest case, it returns the first cell. So that part of what you want is already done for you. If focus isn't moving to the first cell in your collection, then something higher up in the "chain" is the problem.

If your view controller's collection view isn't the `view` property of the view controller, then you'll need to guide the focus chain to the collection yourself:

```
// in your view controller:
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    return myCollectionView;
}
```

From there, the collection view will guide the chain to the specific cell.

Comment: Now we are talking. I wonder why Apple never hires people like you to write their documentation. Instead they write people who hate writing. PERFECT! THANKS!

Comment: If fetching data from some service don't forget to write [self setNeedsFocusUpdate]; after collectionview reloadData/reloadSection statement.

Comment: Any guidance on programattically changing which cell is focused in a collection view?

Answer (score 1):

I have like an updated answer as (UIView *)preferredFocusedView has become deprecated since TVOS 10 and also actually there is a very easy way to get the first cell and even the last cell focused by default

```
- (NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments
{
     return @[myCollectionView.visibleCells.firstObject];
}
```

Or you can use next code to focus the last Cell

```
- (NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments
{
    return @[myCollectionView.visibleCells.lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618066-indexpathforpreferredfocusedview)

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
    return IndexPath(item: self.datasourceArray.count, section: 0)
}
```

You can return any indexPath you want ..

for example`IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)`

Comment: This method is bugged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585956/indexpathforpreferredfocusedview-is-not-being-called

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this UICollectionViewDelegate method and any logic required if you don't want to return true in some cases

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
```

Comment: I have this method in place but now how do I focus a cell?

Comment: Are you asking how to focus a "specific" cell?  Your question says the "first cell".   The above method in my application focuses the first cell.   But if you have multiple focusable items in your view it may require another solution

Comment: no, I mean the first cell. This is not working for me for some reason. BTW, why should this method work if there is nothing there mentioning the first cell? I am not sure if I am explaining myself well. What I want is: the CollectionViewController appears and the first cell is focused (I mean huge in size, as a focused cell is supposed to be in tvOS).

Comment: Maybe post your controller code here.. It works fine for me and shows the first cell focused and in the simulator i can move the right arrow to navigate through my collection view cells.   Did you remove your "preferredFocusedView" method?

Comment: That method isn't what directs focus to go to a particular item; it's more of a way to "veto" allowing focus to move somewhere. If you don't implement that method at all, it's the same as implementing it to always return true.

Comment: Thanks Justin - that makes more sense now based on your answer.