# Custom subclassed collectionview - preferredFocusEnvironments is called, but view is not focused

Tags: tvos, focus-engine

I am trying to implement "remembersLastFocusedIndexPath" for the custom collection view. 
Apple documentation said:

> "If you subclass UICollectionView, you can also implement the same
>   behavior by overriding the preferredFocusEnvironments property, which
>   is defined by the UIFocusEnvironment protocol and adopted by all
>   views."

```
class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView {
  open override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    let sortedVisibleIndexPaths = indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
    if let visibleIndexPath = sortedVisibleIndexPaths[safe: 1] {
        if let cell = cellForItem(at: visibleIndexPath) {
            return [cell]
        }
    }
    return []
  }

  open override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
        LogUtils.logger.error("!")
  }
}
```

preferredFocusEnvironments is called but when I check "context.nextFocusedItem" in "didUpdateFocus" it is a different cell and focus jump randomly. 
Does someone know, where can be a problem? I can not figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indexPathForPreferredFocusedView is not being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585956/indexpathforpreferredfocusedview-is-not-being-called)

Answer (score 0):

`preferredFocusEnvironments` will only allow you to indicate that your collectionView, as a whole, is the preferred focus environment, but you can not use it to prefer individual cells.

To do that you can implement the method `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView` of `UICollectionViewDelegate`

You can find more information on this other issue with a similar question and a working example as a response: [indexPathForPreferredFocusedView is not being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585956/indexpathforpreferredfocusedview-is-not-being-called/48596761#48596761)

Comment: It is not true. I updated code, so it should not be confusing right now. These methods are inside custom collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I had to set ***restoresFocusAfterTransition = false*** to the view controller. It was somehow beating with that.